# Heroku doesn't see an repository that I don't own, but I have write access

Tags: github, heroku, repository

I want to connect to GitHub using Heroku, and I want to connect to repository, which I don't own, but I have write access to.

But only my repositories are shown, and I can pick only my name!

So the question is:
Is it possible and how to connect to GitHub repository, which I don't own, but have write access to, to Heroku?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to enable *automatic* deployment, [write access is not sufficient](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration):

> GitHub repo admin access is required for you to configure automatic GitHub deploys. This is because Heroku has to register a service hook on the GitHub repo, and this action requires admin access. For GitHub organisations, your GitHub account will also need to be a member of the organisation and not an outside collaborator.

So:

1. Do you have *admin*-level access to the repository?
2. Is this repository an organizational repository? If so, are you a member of the organization, or an outside collaborator?

Comment: I have the same issue with OP. I have admin access and I am a member and collaborator on 3 repo in a private organization. But I still can't find those repo in Heroku dashboard and I can only find my own repo. Do you have any idea?

Comment: "I am a member and collaborator"—[those are different things](https://docs.github.com/en/organizations/managing-peoples-access-to-your-organization-with-roles/roles-in-an-organization#about-organization-roles). Please verify that you are an actual member of the organization.